# Totalize a table horizontally and vertically pivot plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to totalize a table horizontally and vertically after performing a pivot?

I have read and looked for what can be done with rollup, but the drawback is that the columns are dynamic

```
PRODUCT | VALUE
:------ | ----:
Shirts  |  1200
tax     |    15
Stocks  |   500
tax     |    20
```

Result

```
SHIRTS | tax (Shirts) | STOCKS | tax (Stocks) | TOTAL
-----: | -----------: | -----: | -----------: | -----:
  1200 |           35 |    500 |           35 |    570
 TOTAL |           35 |    500 |           35 |    570
```

the data structure that I am using is the following, to make use of the pivot, but we must take into account that the columns are dynamic and to use the pivot I use LISTAGG, to build a string for the pivot

```
WITH test_data AS
(
  --PRODUCT | VALUE
  --:------ | ----:
  SELECT 1 AS ord, 'Shirts' AS product, 1200 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ord, 'tax',      15            FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS ord, 'Stocks',   500           FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS ord, 'tax',      20            FROM dual
)

--SELECT * FROM   test_data

, test_data_extended AS
(
  SELECT product, value, LAG(product, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ord) AS pre_product
  FROM test_data
)

, test_data_new AS
(
  SELECT product AS old_product, value, CASE WHEN product = 'tax' THEN 'tax (' || pre_product || ')' ELSE product END AS new_product
  FROM test_data_extended
), new_data AS
(
  SELECT new_product, value
  FROM test_data_new
)    
SELECT * FROM new_data
PIVOT 
( 
  SUM( value )
  FOR new_product IN 
  (
    'Shirts'       AS "Shirts",
    'tax (Shirts)' AS "tax (Shirts)",
    'Stocks'       AS "Stocks",
    'tax (Stocks)' AS "tax (Stocks)"
  )
);
```

Comment: Why are you returning two rows?  Why are you summing `tax` twice?

Comment: What is the structure of (and/or example data from) the tables you are using?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  taxes I must discriminate separately, because they correspond to each article, I'm using LAG to get that pivot

Comment: @Gdaimon . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the correspondence between the tax and the item it refers to.  And, if there is such a correspondence, double counting the tax is not correct.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  if they have a relationship between the tables and the records are unique, and what I am doing is a calculation of each article on a percentage of the taxes, I already had the query as a large total of taxes, but now I need to discriminate

Comment: The way you have it written it looks like the tax entries are independent entries.  Are they intended to be associated with the other transactions (e.g. transaction 1 has a value of 1200 and a tax of 15)? Is this a real life case or an example? Why is the tax not a separate column (as in order_id, product, value, tax for columns) or otherwise associated with the transaction it is related to?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation.  You can get what you want as:

```
select sum(case when product = 'Shirts' then value end) as shirts,
       sum(case when product = 'tax' then value end) as tax_1,
       sum(case when product = 'Stock' then value end) as stock,
       sum(case when product = 'tax' then value end) as tax_2 ,
       sum(value) as total     
from t;
```

I do not understand your data format, where the `tax` is counted twice, so I didn't include that.  I also don't understand why you have a separate row for the total, when you are already totaling things in one row.

Comment: This wont work if additional items are added (for example pants).  Is there a solution that will work for dynamic data?

Comment: @John . . . I can't figure out what the OP really needs.  This is the most sensible solution I can think of.

Comment: @John Exactly, that is the inconvenience that I have, that I must do it dynamically

Comment: @Gdaimon unfortunately there's no dynamic way through Oracle's SQL for pivoting, whereas SQL Server has.